# How does Protobuf Setting Readonly Property

Tags: .net, protobuf-net

I'm intriguied about how this is actually working because I just want to make sure that I'm not mistaken in the fact that my tests succeed.

From the other stackoverflow questions I've read, protobuf can't set readonly properties. But it seems to be doing so just fine.

I have the following class (trimmed to demonstrate)

```
<
ProtoContract()
> _
Public Class WebOrder
    Implements IWebOrder

   Friend Sub New()
      MyBase.New()
      mItems = New Ordered.StockItemsCollection
   end sub 

   Private mItems As Ordered.StockItemsCollection
    <ProtoMember(4)>
    Public ReadOnly Property Items As Ordered.StockItemsCollection
        Get
            Return mItems
        End Get
    End Property

    Private ReadOnly Property COMItems As Ordered.StockItemsCollection Implements IWebOrder.Items
        Get
            Return mItems
        End Get
    End Property
end class
```

When I test this with the following Code it's successful.

```
Dim si As New WebConnector.Ordered.StockItem With {.ItemType = WebConnector.StockItemType.Instruction, 
                    .Description = "test", .Quantity = 5}

activeOrder.Items.Add(si)

Using ms As New MemoryStream
    ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(Of WebConnector.WebOrder)(ms, activeOrder)
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
    ch = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize(Of WebConnector.WebOrder)(ms)
End Using

For Each si In ch.Items
    Debug.Print(si.ItemType.ToString & " --- " & si.Description & " --- x" & si.Quantity)
Next
```

Results:

Instruction --- test --- x5

Is protobuf reaching Into my property and finding the backing field and setting it or is it just `.Add` to the collection or StockItems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For lists, it doesn't *need* to be a read-write; basically, if it is read-only, it just uses `.Add`. If it is read-write, then it also does an extra "is it null? if so, create a new instance of the list, and call the setter". This means that lazy code works, i.e. (with a c# example)

```
[ProtoMember(12)]
public List<Foo> Items {get;set;}
```

However, my *personal preference* with lists is to have them read-only like in your example.

> Is protobuf reaching Into my property and finding the backing field and setting it or is it just .Add to the collection or StockItems?

The latter. It never attempts to resolve fields from properties. If you **explicity mark** fields for serialization, it will work on them - but it won't do that without being told to.

Comment: Thanks once again for the clarification